# Repeat list to create numpy array of specified shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of values with length 10:

```
p = [1, 2, ..., 10]
```

This list corresponds to the second dimension of a 4D array (called `T`):

```
Tshp = np.shape(T)
print(Tshp)
(20, 10, 30, 40)
```

I need to create an array of the same size as `T` with the list `p` repeated over all the other dimensions.

I have tried:

```
new_p = np.tile(p, [Tshp[0], Tshp[2], Tshp[3]])
```

But I get something of size:

```
print(np.shape(new_p))
(20, 30, 400)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is likely using `np.full`. The key here is to use broadcasting to make sure that the right dimensions are filled:

```
result = np.full(T.shape, p.reshape(1, -1, 1, 1))
```

You can acheive a similar result with `tile` by a similar operation:

```
s = list(T.shape)
s[1] = 1
result = np.tile(p.reshape(1, -1, 1, 1), s)
```

Assignment works too:

```
result = np.empty_like(T)
T[:] = p.reshape(1, -1, 1, 1)
```

You can even use direct broadcasting:

```
result = np.broadcast_to(p.reshape(1, -1, 1, 1), T.shape)
```

This is a version that does not copy the data at all.

In all cases, I assumed that you converted `p` to an array, e.g. with `p = np.array(p)`. If not, substitute `p.reshape(...)` with `np.reshape(p, (...))`. You can also omit the leading unit dimensions, since broadcasting aligns to the right. For example, in all cases `1, -1, 1,1` can be replaced with just `-1, 1, 1`.

Comment: The np.full solution worked and is a nice one liner. The numpy documentation on how np.full works with arrays as the fill value is limited. Can you elaborate on how it works? It seems that np.full recognizes that p and T now have the same length along the second dimension and thus it replicates p as the fill value along the second dimension throughout the whole array?

Comment: `np.full` basically broadcasts the assignment, pretty much exactly equivalent to `T[:] = p.reshape(1, -1, 1, 1)`. Normally, you use `full` instead of doing something simple like `some_scalar * np.ones(shape)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [42]: p = np.arange(1,11)
In [43]: p.shape
Out[43]: (10,)
In [44]: T = np.zeros((20,10,30,40),int)
```

If we expand `p` to (10,1,1) shape, then by broadcasting it can be assigned to `T`, expanding to (1,10,1,1) and then to `T.shape`:

```
In [45]: T[:] = p[:,None,None]
```

To use `tile`, first expand `p` to 4d

```
In [48]: T2 = np.tile(p[None,:,None,None],(20,1,30,40))
In [49]: T2.shape
Out[49]: (20, 10, 30, 40)
In [50]: np.allclose(T,T2)
Out[50]: True
```